# Calling javascript function after finishing bean method

Tags: javascript, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I want to execute javascript function after  bean actionListener.I am using JSF 1.2, richfaces 3.3.In my case I want to display a chart after finishing bean's method.My table `tab`is filling but the javascript function didn't work. This is my attempt :

```
<h:form>
<h:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{bean.monActionListener}" reRender="tab">
<a4j:support event="onClick" oncomplete="show()" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:form>

<h:form id="sortie">
<rich:dataTable id="tab" rendered="#{not empty bean.listSortie}" 
value="#{bean.listSortie}" var="raison">

<h:column headerClass="headerleftfacet">
    <h:outputText value="#{raison[0]}">
    </h:outputText>
</h:column>
<h:column headerClass="headermiddlefacet">      
    <h:outputText  value="#{raison[1]}" >
    </h:outputText>
</h:column>

</rich:dataTable>
```

Comment: @BalusC, do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Saying "not working" helps very little. Does the function not execute? Is it executed but doesn't do anything? (In that case show the code of the function) Something else?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by using `<a4j:commandButton>` and `:

```
<h:form>
<h:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{bean.monActionListener}" reRender="tab" oncomplete="alert('ok')">

<h:form>

<a4j:outputPanel id="tab">  
<h:form id="sortie">
<rich:dataTable id="tabb" rendered="#{not empty bean.listSortie}" 
value="#{bean.listSortie}" var="raison">

<h:column headerClass="headerleftfacet">
<h:outputText value="#{raison[0]}">
</h:outputText>
</h:column>
<h:column headerClass="headermiddlefacet">      
<h:outputText  value="#{raison[1]}" >
</h:outputText>
</h:column>

</rich:dataTable>
<h:form>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```