# Executing javascript function after finishing method bean (<a4j:support>)

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

This is my first question. In my project, I'm using JSF 1.2 and richfaces 3.3. I want to execute a javascript function after finishing executing a bean's method.
The method of the bean worked very well and fill the table but the javascript function didn't work. This is my attempt :

```
<h:form>
<h:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{bean.monActionListener}" reRender="table">
<a4j:support event="onClick" oncomplete="show()" />
</h:commandButton>
<h:form>

<h:form>
<rich:dataTable id="table" rendered="#{not empty bean.listU}" 
value="#{bean.listU}" var="u">

 <h:column headerClass="headerleftfacet">
 <h:outputText value="#{u[0]}">
 </h:outputText>
 </h:column>
 <h:column headerClass="headermiddlefacet">      
 <h:outputText  value="#{u[1]}" >
 </h:outputText>
 </h:column>

</rich:dataTable>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this almost the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42976811/1818198)?

Comment: @Makhiel I don't know maybe we have the same problem, can you help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I resolved it by using `<a4j:commandButton>` and `<a4j:outputPanel>`:

```
 <h:form>
 <a4j:commandButton value="Click" actionListener="#{bean.monActionListener}" reRender="tab" oncomplete="alert('ok')" />

 <h:form>

<a4j:outputPanel id="tab">  
<h:form>
<rich:dataTable id="table" rendered="#{not empty bean.listU}" 
 value="#{bean.listU}" var="u">

 <h:column headerClass="headerleftfacet">
 <h:outputText value="#{u[0]}">
  </h:outputText>
 </h:column>
 <h:column headerClass="headermiddlefacet">      
 <h:outputText  value="#{u[1]}" >
 </h:outputText>
   </h:column>

  </rich:dataTable>
  </h:form>
  </a4j:outputPanel>
```